# Unknown driver Informix

Tags: delphi, informix, delphi-xe5, firedac

I am using fireDAC to communicate with my informix driver from delphi application.

After setting the connection parameters using dbExpress gateways :
My connection parameters are:-

```
User_Name=BOSS
Database=new_Mexico
Password=c0ldn0rth
DriverName=Informix
HostName=newMexicoSvr
RDBMS=OTHER
DriverID=TDBX
```

When I set my query active := true. it displays the records in the form while developing. How ever when I execute my application and click on button whicbh activates the query I get following error:

Unknown Driver Informix

Can you please tell what can be the issue with the application?

Comment: When you set the TDBX as DriverID in the connectioneditor, the used dlls/libs are automatic filled in.  Check if these a correct.  Also, you can leave out the 'RDBMS' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after following two steps:

1) Run as Admin

2) Set Target Platform := 32 bit

Works like a charm